# Print an 11 x 17 Microsoft publisher file on 2 pages

Tags: printing, microsoft-publisher

I have an Microsoft publisher file that is 11 x 17.

When I try to print it, it tries to center it on 4 pages.

I want it to print on 2.  (This works by taking the image and printing landscape on two 8.5 x 11 pages.)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've been able to do this is by saving my publisher file as a graphics file.  For the work I do I usually save it as a .png file.  I can then print it on my wide format printer as an 11" X 17" or larger.  So far as I can discover MS Publisher doesn't support printing on paper larger than 8.5" X 14".

Answer (score 1):

I usually print to a pdf printer first (Adobe PDF, if I have it).  In Adobe Acrobat, you can then set your paper size (8.5x11).  Then when you do File->Print, you can set Page Scaling - Tiling.  Very customizable - you can set how much it overlaps, if you want to increase or decrease the size...

The print options you have available might vary depending on what version on Adobe Acrobat you have.